# How to benchmark the decoding of the frame by ffmpeg?

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg, benchmarking

[ What I have done ]

I am trying to measure a performance of different ffmpeg decoders by

- timing how long the call to function `avcodec_decode_video2(..)` takes in ffmpeg.c and running ffmpeg binary the following way

`~/bin/ffmpeg -benchmark_all -loglevel debug -threads 0 -i ~/Documents/video-input.h264 -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=25 video-output.hevc`

- and by timing how long the same function takes in ffplay.c and running the ffplay binary the following way

`~/bin/ffplay ~/Documents/video-input.h264`

In my understanding the average time for the call to that function should be the same whether I am converting the video or playing it, because I am only measuring how long it takes to decode the frame for that video. Is this a wrong way of doing it? Please let me know if I am incorrect. The results I am getting are strange to me - the call to the aforementioned function takes twice as much in ffmpeg binary compared to ffplay binary. I have tried to run ffmpeg binary with `-threads 0` and without it, but the results are still the same(twice as long as ffplay). Could it be because ffplay binary simply utilizes more threads? When I try it with `-threads 1`, ffmpeg takes about 10 times as long as ffplay (which makes sense to me since before it was using several threads and now it is only using 1)

Before I ask my question, I want you to know that I am a beginner in video processing and video encoding/decoding processes.

[My question]

I am wondering what would be an accurate way to measure how long it takes to decode a frame (using 1 thread)? Should I simply measure only how long it takes to call `avcodec_decode_video2(..)` function using the ffmpeg binary, and not the ffplay binary? Would the results be more accurate that way? 
I also tried to enable `-benchmark_all -loglevel debug` options, but it seems like the following message `bench:    64537 decode_video 0.0` is not very helpful if 0.0 is supposed to mean time. (Not sure what the other number means).

Answer (score 26):

## Null muxer

If you want a simple way to benchmark decoding use the [null muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#null):

```
ffmpeg -i input -f null -
```

## Timing decoding

Linux and macOS users can add the `time` command:

```
$ time ffmpeg -i input -f null -
[...]
real    0m5.343s
user    0m20.290s
sys     0m0.230s
```

See `man time` for more info.

## `-benchmark` option

The `-benchmark` option can be added to output CPU time and maximum memory consumption:

```
$ time ffmpeg -i input -benchmark -f null -
[...]
bench: utime=7.314s
bench: maxrss=72280kB
```

## Choosing streams

If you want to just decode a particular stream then use the [map option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

```
ffmpeg -i input -map 0:a:0 -f null -
```

## Threads

You can decode with one thread if you want to:

```
ffmpeg -threads 1 -i input -f null -
```

Not all decoders have threading capabilities and some have several. You can check decoder details such as `ffmpeg -h decoder=h264`.

## Choosing a decoder

There can be several decoders available for a format. You can name the decoder if you don't want to rely on the default:

```
ffmpeg -c:v vp8 -i input -f null -
ffmpeg -c:v libvpx -i input -f null -
```

Comment: It might be worth explaining the difference between the different times - the 'real' time is probably not the most useful for comparisons as it depends on system load, available cores etc.

Comment: An easier way to ignore streams is `-an` to ignore audio streams, or `-vn` ignore video streams.

Comment: @PeterCordes I prefer `-map` because it's more flexible and you can choose (or exclude) specific streams.

Comment: Sure, it has its uses.  But for me by far the most common thing is "leave out the audio" or "leave out the video", and `-an` is faster to type and I don't need to know which stream number is the audio and which is the video.  (e.g. with `-f md5`  to compare two files to see if they have the same audio or video bitstream, even if they're muxed differently).